# Safetly write bytes as UTF-8 characters using strings.Builder?

Tags: string, go

I'm trying to do an exercise where I have to reverse some strings. I heard that Go strings.Builder is the fastest way to create strings at the moment, so I did the following:

```
func String(toReverse string) string {
    var reversedString strings.Builder

    for i := len(toReverse) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        reversedString.WriteByte(toReverse[i])
    }

    return reversedString.String()
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't work with multibyte test cases like this:

> Hello, 世界

becomes

> "\u008c\u0095ç\u0096¸ä ,olleH"

Thanks.

Comment: You're reversing the bytes, not the characters. The [utf8](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) package should help you here. Although there are still many corner cases when reversing Unicode. Generally speaking, this cannot be done safely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is possible - and the default - to access a string's individual bytes by index, a Go string is also convertible to an array of runes, which represent individual Unicode code points.

First of all you need to cast your string into a []rune, and iterate on that:

```
func String(toReverse string) string {
    var reversedString strings.Builder
    runes := []rune(toReverse)

    for i := len(runes) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        reversedString.WriteRune(runes[i])
    }

    return reversedString.String()
}
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/WYn_MGAGw_x for a live demo.